# Some questions is occur when using ViewPager and Fragment

Tags: android

> it just a question about how to load fragment
>   There is concrete code:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    List<Fragment> fragments = new LinkedList<>();
    BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
    fragments.add(blankFragment);
    handler = blankFragment.getHandler();
    ContactPagerAdapter adapter = new ContactPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

}

> Fragment -Just print some log:

```
class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d("TAG", "-->>19 handleMessage");
    }
};

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TAG", "-->>34 onCreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TAG", "-->>40 onCreateView");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}
```

}

> and the logcat print:
>       -->>19 handleMessage
>       -->>34 onCreate
>       -->>40 onCreateView

I am not understand why it print these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following chain of events results in the output mentioned in your question getting printed:

1. `MainActivity`'s `onResume()` method gets called which posts an empty message to the `Handler` attached to the main (UI) thread's message queue. This prints `-->>19 handleMessage` to the log.
2. The `MainActivity` is now ready to interact with the user and its UI containing the `BlankFragment` needs to be displayed. `SupportFragmentManager` initializes `BlankFragment` by calling its `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` methods in that order. This prints `-->>34 onCreate` and `-->>40 onCreateView` respectively.

In `onCreate()` fragment callback, you should perform one-time initializations and in `onCreateView()` you should return the `View` hierarchy to be displayed by the fragment.

Comment: I see, but when i invoke viewPager.setAdapter(), why didn't  fragment created immediately.  Until onResume() method executed ,  the Fragment is not created yet.

Comment: The fragment gets created (instantiated) the instant you execute 'new BlankFragment()'. But Android system calls the 'onCreate()' and 'onCreateView()' lifecycle callback methods of 'BlankFragment' only when the fragment (or the ViewPager containing it) needs to be shown, i.e, when the activity resumes.

Comment: I think now i am understand, so I modify handler.sendMessage() to  handler.sendMessageDelay(fragment,500),  this may be show the some result, but sometimes it will good, and the bad effect is week.

Comment: Posting a message with a delay should work provided that the delay is sufficiently large. Use 'onActivityCreated()' method of Fragment which will only get called after 'onCreate()' and 'onCreateView()' are called.